# Angular HTTP GET option return 403 for S3 json files

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, ngx-translate

**I'm trying to fetch translation files from S3, but receiving error code 403 from AWS.**

I'm using ngx-translte library to translate the web site, I implemented my own custom translate loader.
but i'm still get 403 on get option(And to my knowledge this is chrome request)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class HttpTranslateLoaderService implements TranslateLoader {
    contentHeader = new HttpHeaders({ "Content-Type": "application/json", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" });

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
        var apiAddress = environment.bucketUrl + "mobile/assets/i18n/" + lang + ".json";
        return Observable.create(observer => {
            this.http.get(apiAddress, { headers: this.contentHeader }).subscribe((res: Response) => {
                observer.next(res.json());
                observer.complete();
            },
                error => {
                    //  failed to retrieve from api, switch to local
                    this.http.get(`/assets/i18n/${lang}.json`).subscribe((res: Response) => {
                        observer.next(res.json());
                        observer.complete();
                    })
                }
            );
        });
    }
}
```

All AWS permissions issues have been checked

I expect to receive the file which has public access, but still getting forbidden error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually i resolved the issue!

*I don't know if this is the right way but it works for me.*

Instead of using the angular http service, I used built in fetch  function and surround with from function of rxjs.

**Updated translation loader**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Observable, of, from } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class HttpTranslateLoaderService implements TranslateLoader {
    contentHeader = new HttpHeaders({ "Content-Type": "application/json", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" });
    httpParams = new HttpParams().set('cacheblock', 'true')
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
        var apiAddress = environment.bucketUrl + "mobile/assets/i18n/" + lang + ".json";
        return Observable.create(observer => {
            from(fetch(apiAddress)).subscribe((res: Response) => {
                observer.next(res.json());
                observer.complete();
            },
                error => {
                    //  failed to retrieve from api, switch to local
                    this.http.get(`/assets/i18n/${lang}.json`).subscribe((res: Response) => {
                        observer.next(res.json());
                        observer.complete();
                    })
                }
            );
        });
    }
}
```